# How to validate the correct hierarchy of parent child tree

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have a function that accepts a hierarchy data(parent -child relationship), this data will be saved into the database and insert it one by one in accordance with its hierarchy. To make sure to save the data in the correct hierarchy, I need to validate it first before saving. Below is the sample hierarchy. If you can see the child 1.3 and child 1.3.1, the hierarchy is wrong and the validation should return a message that hierarchy is not correct. The number of '>' symbols indicates the hierarchy ordinal of the item, for example, '>' level 1, '>>' level 2, '>>>' level 3 and so on.

Entity class

```
 public class Person
        {
            public string Name
            { get; set; }

            public int Level
            { get; set; }


        }
```

Code

```
            var text = textBox1.Text.Replace("\r", "\n").Replace("\n\n", "\n").Trim();
            string[] array = text.Split(new char[]
            {
                '\n'
            });

            List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                string text2 = array[i];
                Person person = new Person
                {
                    // Regex.Replace(str, @"[^\d]", String.Empty);
                    Name = Regex.Replace(text2.Trim(), ">", String.Empty),
                    Level = text2.Trim().LastIndexOf(">", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1,
                };
                list.Add(person);
            }
```

Sample text

```
   Parent1
    >child 1.1
      >>child 1.1.1
        >>>child 1.1.2
    >child 1.2
    >child 1.3
        >>>child 1.3.1
          >>>>child 1.3.2
    Parent2
      >>child 2.1
```

Comment: Please show your code, classes, data structures.

Comment: gdir, updated with sample code

Comment: How do you link a person to its parent or a parent to its childs? Your Person class doesn't store that information.

Comment: gdir,That's the missing part in the code, once it passed the validation, it should be store in another class for parent child. That is why i need to validate first the data before saving it to another container that has a parent child relationship.